# Poorly calibrated probabilities but good classification in confusion matrix

Tags: classification, r-caret, confusion-matrix, calibration, imbalanced-data

I have an imbalanced data set. My goal is to balance sensitivity and specificity via the confusion matrix. I used glmnet in r with class weights. The model does well at balancing the sensitivity/specificity, but I looked at the calibration plot, and the probabilities are not well calibrated. I have read about calibrating probabilities, but I am wondering if it matters if my goal is to produce class predictions. If it does matter, I have not found a way to calibrate the probabilities when using caret::train().

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been widely discussed, especially in some answers by [Stephan Kolassa](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/stephan-kolassa). I will try to summarize the main take-home messages for your specific question.

From a pure statistical point of view your interest should be on producing as output a probability for each class of any new data instance. As you deal with [unbalanced data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) such probabilities can be small which however - as long as they are correct - is not an issue. Of course, [some models can give you poor estimates of the class probabilities](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html). In such cases, the calibration allows you to better calibrate the probabilities obtained from a given model. This means that whenever you estimate for a new observation a probability ***p*** of belonging to the target class, then ***p*** is indeed its true probability to be of that class.

If you are able to obtain a good probability estimator, then balancing sensitivity or specificity is not part of the statistical part of your problem, but rather of the [decision component](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email). Such the final decision will likely need to use some kind of threshold. Depending on the costs of type I and II errors, the cost-optimal threshold might change; however, [an optimal decision might also include more than one threshold.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352)

Ultimately, you really have to be careful about which is the specific need of the end-user of your model, because this is what is going to determine the best way of taking decisions using it.